# Appcelerator Titanium webview.toImage

Tags: android, webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am attempting to save a convert a webview to an image.  The issue I am running into is when run on an android device the "Canvas" items in the webview are not being rendered in the created blob.  Has anyone else run into this and is there a solution to this issue.  Not that is overly complicated but here is a snippet of the code I am using.

```
Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(webView.toImage());
```

Works fine on iOS, but Android does not seem to convert Canvas items.

Answer (score 1):

I am also able to reproduce this issue. If you want this issue to be resolved quickly you can create a Jira ticket [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org). Appcelerator team is very quick to response. Do add sample test code that worked for iOS but not for Android and steps to reproduce.